# Can't add ALAssets to NSOperationQueue from enumeration block

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, alassetslibrary

I'm trying to enumerate through the `ALAssetLibrary` to retrieve all saved photos. From the enumeration block, I'm trying to to send each `ALAsset` for asynchronous processing by passing it to an `NSInvocationOperation` object, then adding that to an `NSOperationQueue`. However, only the first `ALAsset` object is properly passed to the processing method. All subsequent assets are just passed as nil.

Here is my code:

ViewDidLoad:

```
queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
     [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
     [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
      {
          if (! result) {
              return;
          }

          NSInvocationOperation* operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(processAsset:) object:result];
          [queue addOperation:operation];

          return;
      }];

 } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"%@", error);
 }];
```

And the -processAsset method

```
- (void)processAsset:(ALAsset *)asset
{
    NSLog(@"Asset: %@", asset);
    // Asset is nil after the first iteration
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `ALAssets` objects are deallocated when the `ALAssetsLibrary` that obtained them goes out of scope.  If you want to do what you're doing, you'll need to keep a strong reference to `library`, and then deallocate `library` when you're done with it.

(In your case, they deallocate at the end of `viewDidLoad`.)